# OAuth Signin not working in FireFox but Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

Like the title says, I can login in my application using the Google OAuth boilerplate code taken from [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list).

This lets me login in Google Chrome, in Firefox however the login-window just closes and `GoogleAuth.currentUser` is still no valid user. `GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()` also returns `false`.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using.   the link you have supplied does not contain any of the code you have mentioned.

Comment: @DaImTo It does, just select "Full sample"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried different systems and now finally a fresh install (portable), there it worked, seems one of my addons was causing this...

With a bit trying about I found out that it was the extension [Kee](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keefox/) in my case.